# Redundant static data

Tags: c++, xml, vector, static

This question applies to any type of static data. I'm only using `int` to keep the example simple.

I am reading in a large XML data file containing ints and storing them in a `vector<int>`. For the particular data I'm using, it's very common for the same value to be repeated consecutively many times.

```
<Node value="4" count="4000">
```

The `count` attribute means that the value is to be repeated x number of times:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4000; i++)
    vec.push_back(4);
```

It seems like a waste of memory to store the same value repeatedly when I already know that it is going to appear 4000 times in a row. However, I need to be able to index into the vector at any point.

For larger data objects, I know that I can just store a pointers but that would still involve storing 4000 identical pointers in the example above.

Is there any type of strategy to deal with an issue like this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use two vectors. The first vector contains the indices, the second one the actual values.

Fill in the indices vector such that the value for all indices between indices[i-1] and indices [i] is in values[i].

Then use binary search on the indices array to locate the position in the values array. Binary search is very efficient (O(log n)), and you will only use a fraction of the memory compared to the original approach.

If you assume the following data:

```
4000 ints with value "4"
followed by 200 ints with value "3"
followed by 5000 ints with value "10"
```

You would create an index vector and value vector and fill it like this:

```
indices = {4000, 4200, 9200}; // indices[i+1] = indices [i] + new_count or 0
values = {4,3,10};
```

As suggested in the other answers, you should probably wrap this in an operator[].

Comment: Ultimately, it's a tradeoff: you can offer O(1) access and O(N) memory or O(log(N)) access and O(1) memory.

Comment: That's an interesting strategy that I hadn't considered. My only real concern is blocks of non-repeating data between the repeating chunks. Maybe my implementation of operator[] could somehow leave gaps in the ranges of `indices` and be smart enough to look in another place if it's not found there.

Comment: A more complex version could use a third array, with pointers to vectors (or nullptr). For each larger non-repeating sequence, create a new array and store the pointer in the third array, and its boundaries in indices (as above). Then check the third array; if it contains a nullptr, use values[i], otherwise retrieve the value from the stored array using relative_index = in_index - indices[i].

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to write a specific class instead of using `vector`.
Your class should just hold the number of times an item occurs in a list and compute the index in a smart way so you can easily retrieve an element based on the index.

Comment: I assume *list* is just a generic name for a container here, not specifically an `std::list`.

Comment: @Gorpik yes, list is to be considered as a generic name here.

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap your data into some objects with vector-like interface (`operator[]` and so on), so you can hide implementation detail (that is you are not actually storing 4000 numbers) yet provide similar interface.